# c# Method to return a string?

Tags: c#, loops

This method is supposed to have a loop and return a string. How do I do that? This what I have so far. I'm new to C#.

```
public string BLoop()
{
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0}   bottles of beer.", i));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

++ I tried all the thing you suggested but I think I should rephrase the method is supposed to return a string that is printed by the main.

Comment: Please [learn to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+return+string&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS566US566&oq=c%23+return+string&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0j69i60j0l2.2111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) first....

Comment: This is a basic in c# and develoment.Please Learn a little before asking us to do your homework or whatever you are doing.

Comment: *I tried all the thing you suggested but I think I should rephrase the method is supposed to return a string that is printed by the main.* - that's exactly what my answer gives you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you need to return the string constructed in your loop (and not just some arbitrary string as in the other answers). You need to build a string instead of just writing the strings out, then return that string:

```
public string BLoop()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0} bottles of beer.", i));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {0} bottles of beer on the wall.", i-1));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Note that I've also amended the second line of your loop to eliminate the redundant `String.Format` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a string, than just add a `return` statement

```
public string BLoop()
{
        for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0}   bottles of beer.", i));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    return "a string";
}
```

Comment: I snickered at this post. Nice one, besides it DOES answer the question ^.^

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `return` keyword:

```
public string BLoop()
{
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0}   bottles of beer.", i));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    return "this is some string to return";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build string in your loop and then return its string value.

```
public string BLoop()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0}   bottles of beer.", i));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No clue what you're actually asking for, but if you're supposed to return the entire song as a big string then do this:

```
public string BLoop()
{
    var song = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
    {
        song.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0} bottles of beer.", i));
        song.AppendLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
        song.AppendLine();
    }
    return song.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps...good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's just another answer of a simplest question. Use 'return' statement after the loop.

```
    public string BLoop()
    {
        string sStatus = "Process Started";
        Console.WriteLine(sStatus);

        for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0}   bottles of beer.", i));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Take one down, pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.", i, i - 1));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        sStatus = "Process Completed";
        return sStatus;
    }
```