# passing arguments and variables

Tags: c#

here is my main method, and when i call to Print status. I set the params for PrintStatus and I'm getting an error about eligibility not being used and I cannot figure it out. I'm new to passing arguments, we just went over it in class.

"Error  CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'eligibility'  Program10   I:\Program10\Program10\Program10.cs 150 Active
"

```
static void Main()
    {
        int id, age, exp;
        double avgAge, avgExp;
        char type;
        string eligibility;



        OpenFiles();
        PrintReportHeadings();
        while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ParseLineIn(out id, out type, out age, out exp);
            PrintStatus(type, age, exp, eligibility);
            PrintDetailLine(id, type, age, exp);
        }
        CloseFiles();
    }
```

not sure how to fix this..

```
static void PrintStatus(char type, int age, int exp, string eligibility)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case 'm':
            case 'M':

                if (age < 55 && exp < 20)
                    eligibility = ("lack of experience age");
                else if (age >= 55 && exp >= 20)
                    eligibility = ("can retire");
                else if (age >= 55 && exp < 20)
                    eligibility = ("lack of experience");
                else if (age < 55 && exp >= 20)
                    eligibility = ("underage");
                else
                    eligibility = ("Your entry is invalid");
                break;

            case 'w':
            case 'W':

                if (age < 63 && exp < 25)
                    eligibility = ("lack of exp age");
                else if (age >= 63 && exp >= 25)
                    eligibility = ("can retire");
                else if (age >= 63 && exp < 25)
                    eligibility = ("lack of exp");
                else if (age < 63 && exp >= 25)
                    eligibility = ("lack age");
                else
                    eligibility = ("Your entry is invalid");
                break;

            case 's':
            case 'S':

                if (age < 60 && exp < 24)
                    eligibility = ("lack of exp age");
                else if (age >= 60 && exp >= 24)
                    eligibility = ("can retire");
                else if (age >= 60 && exp < 24)
                    eligibility = ("lack of exp");
                else if (age < 60 && exp >= 24)
                    eligibility = ("underage");
                else
                    eligibility = ("Your entry is invalid");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should give a default value to _eligibility_ for example _eligibility="";_

Comment: Do you understand that changes to the parameter named `eligibility` in `PrintStatus` don't affect your local variable named `eligibility` in `Main`? It sounds like your `PrintStatus` method should be called `GetEligibility`, and *return* a string...

Comment: thats what i want to do actually, Im struggling to figure out how to get it to return the string though

Comment: Since your question has nothing to do with what you apparently need to achieve it is hard to provide good answer. Reading any book/tutorial on C# would be generally benecial for you, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803073/c-sharp-method-to-return-a-string should give you enough of an answer (and approximate score for this type of question).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the string *eligibility* with the code of PrintStatus then the simplest way to do it is to return the string and assign it to *eligibility* on return from PrintStatus

```
static string PrintStatus(char type, int age, int exp)
{
    string result = "";
    switch (type)
    {
        case 'm':
        case 'M':

            if (age < 55 && exp < 20)
                result = ("lack of experience age");
            else if (age >= 55 && exp >= 20)
                result = ("can retire");
            else if (age >= 55 && exp < 20)
                result = ("lack of experience");
            else if (age < 55 && exp >= 20)
                result = ("underage");
            else
                result = ("Your entry is invalid");
            break;

        // etc other case
    }
    return result:
}
```

At this point you call PrintStatus in this way

```
....
eligibility = PrintStatus(type, age, exp);
....
```

To understand why your actual code cannot change the *eligibility* string you should search around about the concepts of passing parameters by value and passing by reference. A good explanation is from this famous article

[Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: this does work for me, however when running the file, it has no output of the assigned string to the data file.
even after
`static void PrintDetailLine(int id, char type, int age, int exp, string eligibility)
        {
            fileOut.WriteLine("{0}  {1}    {2}    {3}", id, age, exp, eligibility);
        }`

Comment: Probably you need to pass the value of _eligibility_ to PrintDetails and then, inside that method, do whatever is required to print the string.

Comment: Weird, if that is the updated code then I can't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: it wasn't saving the solution. had to re-open file. it does work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells well already. Your local variable eligibility is not assigned a value, before using it.

```
string eligibility = "whatever";
```

shall remove the error message.

Also your function shall be defined like:

```
static void PrintStatus(char type, int age, int exp, out string eligibility);
```

Comment: the thing about it is... in this program, im reading in information and based on type i need it to place the correct string in eligibility and output it based on the type.

Comment: Yes, put a "out" before eligibility shall also fix the problem. You must tell function that this variable is for output, not need to initialize.

Comment: Also, use string as the return type is more readable: `static string PrintStatus(char type, int age, int exp)` then at the end of your function, add `return eligibility`. To use it `eligibility = PrintStatus(type, age, exp)`

Answer (score 0):

Because the variables are local, you need to assign a default value to them:

```
    int id = 0, age, exp;
    double avgAge = 0, avgExp;
    char type;
    string eligibility = "";
```

Do the same for all local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get a value for your eligibility. Assuming this is the case I have re-written your PrintStatus method and renamed it GetPrintStatus.

```
 static string GetPrintStatus(char type, int age, int exp)
    {
        switch (char.ToLower(type))
        {
            case 'm':
                if (age < 55 && exp < 20)
                    return ("lack of experience age");
                if (age >= 55 && exp >= 20)
                    return ("can retire");
                if (age >= 55 && exp < 20)
                    return ("lack of experience");
                if (age < 55 && exp >= 20)
                    return ("underage");
                return ("Your entry is invalid");
            case 'w':
                if (age < 63 && exp < 25)
                    return ("lack of exp age");
                if (age >= 63 && exp >= 25)
                    return ("can retire");
                if (age >= 63 && exp < 25)
                    return ("lack of exp");
                if (age < 63 && exp >= 25)
                    return ("lack age");
                return ("Your entry is invalid");
            case 's':

                if (age < 60 && exp < 24)
                    return ("lack of exp age");
                if (age >= 60 && exp >= 24)
                    return ("can retire");
                if (age >= 60 && exp < 24)
                    return ("lack of exp");
                if (age < 60 && exp >= 24)
                    return ("underage");
                return ("Your entry is invalid");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

To use it you would have to include the following line in your main method. Replace this;

```
PrintStatus(type, age, exp, eligibility);
```

whit this;

```
eligibility =  GetPrintStatus(type, age, exp);
```

type, age and exp must be given values like this;

```
age = 35;
```

This must be done before you call the GetPrintStatus method.

Since you are learning I'll explain some of the changes; next to GetPrintStatus is the word "string", this means that the function will return a string (previously you called it eligibility) and char.ToLower(type) make the character you pass in lower case so it no longer matters whether its M or m. This can be simplified further but it would not look much like the code you gave.

Good luck.

Comment: i fixed the eligibility not returning a value problem, but it's not writing it to the output file
       `Employee Report               

 ID  Age   Exp    Eligibility 
---- ---   ---    ----------- 
1235  45    20    
2536  55    21    
5894  60    30    
4597  75    35    
2597  35    10    
5689  40    20    
5489  55    39    
5872  60    40    
5569  55    25    
5566  80    20    
8865  59    35    
5598  65    35`

Comment: If you describe what your application is supposed to I might be able to help